# How to submit in-app purchases to review when they are in status "Approved"

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, appstore-approval

We got 2 rejection with the following reason:

We are unable to complete the review of your app because one or more of your in-app purchase products have not been submitted for review. Please note, Weekly subscription and Monthly subscription with new reduced prices were not submitted for review.

Weekly subscription and Monthly subscription in status "Approved", so we can not submit it like in first time when they in status "Ready for submit".

Comment: Did you check these similar questions? https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=We+are+unable+to+complete+the+review+of+your+app+because+one+or+more+of+your+in-app+purchase+products+have+not+been+submitted+for+review.

Comment: @MartinR, yes. All this questions reference to cases when it is first submission. Our in-app purchases got approved earlier, something like 6 months ago.

Comment: One possible solution, that we think could work, is to change one random metadata in our in-app purchases. This could force our purchases to be submitted to review. But again, it just a coin flip.